# In Python, is it acceptable to use a metaclass to add and remove many class attributes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance, metaclass

Specifically, is it acceptable/good practice to use a class attribute to create more class attributes, and then remove the original?

Say I have a superclass. From that, I derive many subclasses, but all of these need some class attributes defined. If I were to do this normally, it would look something like:

```
class Bar(Foo):
    someval = 0
    someotherval = ('a', 'b', 'c')
    importantval = [1, 2, 3]
    thisval = 'this'
    names = ['John', 'Joe']
```

Every subclass would need to define all of these attributes. However, if we somehow use one variable to create all of these it would look something like:

```
class Bar(Foo):
    classvars = (0, ('a', 'b', 'c'), [1, 2, 3], 'this', ['John', 'Joe'])
```

Then, after the class is created, it would internally look the same as the version of the class where we define all of the attributes separately.

See, I tried to do this before by using just a superclass without a metaclass with something like:

```
class Foo:
    @classmethod
    def __init__(cls, val):
        cls.val = val

class Bar(Foo):
    Foo.__init__(5)
```

But if you know how `@classmethod` works, then you know that `cls` ends up being a class `Foo` reference, instead of a class `Bar` reference (when called during `Bar`'s creation, and `cls` only ends up being a `Bar` reference during a `Bar` instance creation). I then also tried to use `@staticmethod` instead, but, to my knowledge, when creating a class, you cannot reference to the class being created outside of a method definition.

i.e.

```
class Bar(Foo):
    Foo.__init__(Bar, 5)
```

That would raise a NameError (if `Foo`'s `__init__` method were a static method).

Eventually, I learned about metaclasses, and I figured out that I could do this:

```
class MetaFoo(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, namespace):
        super(MetaFoo, cls).__init__(name, bases, namespace)
        if '_superclass' not in namespace:  # A special attribute to distinguish between classes that we want to affect and those that we don't
            attrnames = ('someval', 'someotherval', 'importantval', 'thisval', 'names')
            if 'classvars' in namespace:
                for attr, attrname in zip(getattr(cls, 'classvars'), attrnames):
                    setattr(cls, attrname, attr)
                    namespace[attrname] = attr
                delattr(cls, 'classvars')
            else:  # Allow the definitions to be separate, instead of through "classvars", but also make sure that all the required attributes are defined
                for attrname in attrnames:
                    if attrname not in namespace:
                        raise AttributeError('"%s" not found.' % attrname)


class Foo(metaclass=MetaFoo):
    _superclass = True  # The value of this attribute doesn't matter

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def dosomething(self):
        return self.value * self.someval  # Can use type(self).someval for the class attribute, as long as the class itself is never passed as self


class Bar(Foo):
    classvars = (5, ('c', 'b', 'a'), [3, 2, 1], 'This', ['Jimmy', 'Bob'])
```

What the above does, in short, is if it finds a class attribute called `classvars`, it uses that to create other class attributes, then it removes `classvars`. In this example, doing:

```
class Bar(Foo):
    classvars = (5, ('c', 'b', 'a'), [3, 2, 1], 'This', ['Jimmy', 'Bob'])
```

gives you an identical result to:

```
class Bar(Foo):
    someval = 5
    someotherval = ('c', 'b', 'a')
    importantval = [3, 2, 1]
    thisval = 'This'
    names = ['Jimmy', 'Bob']
```

My main question is: is it acceptable (or is it generally avoided for a some reason) to use a metaclass in this way, especially if you are already using a metaclass for a good reason?

A side question is: is there any way to accomplish this without a metaclass?

Comment: I wouldn't do that, simply because "Explicit is better than implicit."

Comment: @cco I know that is about the coding style itself, but what if you make it clear (through comments in the code/documentation) that the two styles of creating `Bar` are identical, it's just that the one is much quicker and more efficient. If you have like 10 different class variables that need defined and 25 different subclasses that need created, you'd need at least 275 lines doing it normally, versus only 50 lines doing it the short way.

Comment: I'll grant you shorter, but I doubt it's quicker (to run, not to write) or more efficient.  For me, the separation of the names from the values is a significant loss; different opinions are equally valid.  On the question of another way to do this, you could use a class decorator, which would make the `_superclass` dance unnecessary and make the magic a little less hidden (a Good Thing, IMHO).

Comment: Are you creating classes at runtime? Are you automating module creation? What problem are you trying to solve?- For your purposes, why is a subclass definition with a single `classvars` attribute *better* than a subclass definition with all its class attributes *written out*?

Comment: @cco I meant it would be more efficient as far as writing the code goes: instead of taking 20 minutes to code all the subclasses, it may only take 2.

I don't even know how I would do this with a class decorator, but I do know how to do it with a metaclass (which is actually pretty easy), which is why I've done it this way.

Comment: @wwii Specifically, I was creating a currency module, equipped with a subclassable `Currency` class and a `Coin` class (the `Coin` class being for the constituents of the currency). Since you have to subclass `Coin` for each "coin" (constituent of the currency), most times, you will have to subclass many coins. In addition to that, if I were to create many currencies, I would have to subclass `Coin` for each coin in each of those currencies. That's a lot of subclassing. If I were to define all the attributes separately, it could take hours, versus maybe a half an hour the shorter way.

Comment: The class decorator works much the same way; the constructed class is passed to the decorator, which can then modify the class as desired and return it.

Comment: @cco Well, I know how a decorator works in general, I just meant that I wouldn't know exactly how to set it up to do this. But in addition to that, I was hoping to not have to do something specific each time you create another subclass. I'm assuming that I would have to decorate each subclass, which is something that, in my case, is not really desirable. The other nice thing about a metaclass is that if you want to do a bunch of repeated checks/calls/manipulation and stuff each time a subclass is created, you can do that with a metaclass very easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you could do that. But I don't know if it is simply better than copying+pasting all the needed attributes around.

If you will do this,  to keep a minimum of readability for one looking at the code of one of your subclasses - and that includes you one week from now - you should at least use a dictionary instead of a sequence. That way you will always know which value maps to each attribute when looking at a subclass.

Also, have in mind that if at least some of the attributes have good default values that would be valid for a number of the subclasses, the inheritance mechanism is great in keeping these defaults while allowing you to explicitly declare only the attributes you really need to be different for each subclass (and typing less cruft than using a dictionary, which will require at a minimum extra quotes around the names).

Otherwise, as far as the language is concerned, that is ok. You'd rather have an special attribute name on a base class allowing you to enter the required/desired attributes names on the base class body, instead of having them hardcoded on the metaclass: that looks really "uncivilized". By having an attribute on the baseclass, the metaclass can be reusable for different object hierarchies.

(just use a  `for` iterating on the `bases` parameter to the metaclass to check if the parameter with attribute names is present there)

Ah, as it is part of the question: about removing class attributes that won't be useful after class creation, using the metaclass - that is perfectly ok.

Comment: As far as inheritance goes, each of the attributes in my actual situation have to be specific to the subclass, they can't have a default value, or it wouldn't make sense, as they are specific to what the subclass represents. Using a dictionary would barely eliminate the problem of having to repeat the names and also type the values. A superclass attribute for the attribute names is a good idea, but I didn't do that because for my case, the specific attributes needed are not at all likely to change (plus, if needed, I will just use comments for name "hints"). Overall, good, helpful answer.

Comment: As I said: no, there is nothing against it - the major drawback is the one I outlined - but nothing that a comment line with the parameter order can't fix there.